# CloudWatch Logs not showing up anymore after switching from Alexa-hosted to custom skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cloudwatch

Since I switched from building an **Alexa hosted** skill to building a **custom skill** using the **ASK SDK** no logs are showing up in my **CloudWatch interface**. Before I could simply click on **Code > Logs: Amazon CloudWatch** and were presented with the logs of the previous session. If I navigate now to the cloud watch console no logs for my custom skill are showing up. I am sure that this is because of wrong configuration but sadly I could not find any documentation about this online. Maybe someone had the same issue before and can help me out with his expertise. Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: In your AWS Lambda Console, you should have the Monitoring tab with CloudWatch logs

Comment: I added a screenshot showing all possible options. The Logs and log groups also does not contain anything. The monitoring tab ist not shown at all, although I think I am logged in with my admin account

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to my question. All my resources like EC2 instances were running in the **eu-west-1** region. I had to go through all regions in cloud watch to find out that the log files for my alexa skill are stored in the **us-east-1** region. Only there, they are visible.

Comment: Thanks! I have my Alexa-Hosted skill deployed in eu-west-1, but logs are stored in us-east-1. I couldn't see them, because "Cloudwatch Logs" button was redirecting me to eu-west-1.